# Tomcat vulnerability patching

Tags: linux, web-server, tomcat, security

I had a tomcat vulnerability scan in my linux server and report came as Important: Authentication bypass and information disclosure (CVE-2011-3190) .My apache tomcat is of version 6.0.24.
[tomcat security](http://tomcat.apache.org/security-6.html) say that it need to be upgarded and patch .Can someone help me with this patching process.

Answer (score 0):

### Use updated package

As we don't know your OS, we cannot help you.

### Install updated tomcat version

When you inspect http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2011-3190/ you see that you have to install at least 6.0.34.

Current release is 6.0.36.

So go to http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi and install it.

### patching

Grab the tomcat 6.0.24 sources with:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc6.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_6_0_24

The patch can be obtained with:

```
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1162959
```

Add the patch to the sources and build tomcat6 yourself. See the [BUILDING.txt](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc6.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_6_0_24/BUILDING.txt) document in the sources.

Double cross your fingers that the patch against 6.0.33 make sense also for 6.0.24.

#### WARNING

You creating a version nobody else has tested. No quality assurance has been done by the tomcat people from apache.

Comment: My OS operating system is RHEL 5.5 64bit .I know that it can also be solved by upgarding to 6.0.36.But my tomcats are preproduction server .So only patching is possible .Currently I am using tomcat 6.0.29

Comment: From the fix reports i see that , patch is available for this .But these are two .java files .How these are used to patch?I guess tomcat-coyote.tar contains the same files in as classes .So when i compile these [patch package](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1162959) It show errors too as object not avalible

Comment: See the update.